# How to get user's circle with google acess token

Tags: google-api, access-token

I have user's google access token and i can get user's information with below urls
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=...
or
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/user_id?access_token=...

My question is: How can i get user's circles with access token? Is it possible?
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You [can't get information](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=9) about a Google+ users circles.